# How to compile ghostscript static in Visual c++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, ghostscript

How to compile ghostscript static in Visual c++?

What changes must be made to the msvc.mak file?

Thx

Comment: What do you mean by 'compile Ghostscript "static"' ?

Comment: i need ghostscript as library, not DLL.

Comment: Really ? Why can't you use a DLL ?

Comment: It is more convenient to install, distribute and support department.

Comment: So is this for an open source project ? Which one ? Where can I get a look at it ?

Comment: at the moment it is a project that is starting.
Do you know how to compile ghostscritp as a library and not DLL?

Comment: An open source project ? In which case support hardly seems like an issue. If its a commercial project then you should **start** by looking at the licence, you're going to need a commercial licence to use Ghostscript like this. Once you have a commercial licence, you;re entitled to support, without it, you're on your own (and of course potentially illegally using the software)

Comment: Ok, did not know the issue of licenses. Thx